# How do I filter records by locale using gem mobility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobility

I have a table mobility_string_translations, but I do not understand how to get to it.

Now I have three records. Two records in German and one in Spanish. I want to get only those records that are in German.

this not working:

```
all_de_posts = Post.i18n.find_by(locale: :de)
```

Comment: What columns does `posts` table have?

Comment: I noticed you tagged this with ruby-on-rails-3. Are you really using Mobility with RoR3? It is not tested against versions that old, the oldest it has been tested against is RoR 4.2. You may have some issues with it using such an old version of Rails.

Comment: @ChrisSalzberg sorry, it's mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you may have a column.(Lets say title.)

On your model `post.rb` you will have something like this:

```
        class Post < ApplicationRecord
          extend Mobility
          translates :title,  type: :string, locale_accessors: [:en, :de]
        end
```

The type is important in order to get the :de records(or the :en).

At `schema.rb` wou will see a table mobility_**string**_translations

```
  create_table "mobility_string_translations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "locale", null: false
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "value"
    t.integer "translatable_id", null: false
    t.string "translatable_type", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["translatable_id", "translatable_type", "key"], name: "index_mobility_string_translations_on_translatable_attribute"
    t.index ["translatable_id", "translatable_type", "locale", "key"], name: "index_mobility_string_translations_on_keys", unique: true
    t.index ["translatable_type", "key", "value", "locale"], name: "index_mobility_string_translations_on_query_keys"
  end
```

Well now at your console find your records with **locale: :de**

```
irb:> Post.all

irb:> Mobility::ActiveRecord::StringTranslation.where(locale: :de)
```

As you can see at your schema.rb --> "mobility_string_translations"  you can  play around with your columns in order to find exactly what you want.

Comment: Excellent!

locale_posts_ids = Mobility::ActiveRecord::StringTranslation
                          .where(
                            locale: I18n.locale,
                            translatable_type: 'Post'
                          )
                          .pluck(:translatable_id)
    @posts = Post.where(id: locale_posts_ids)

Comment: Perfect! Glad i could help :)

Comment: I see sometimes this exception: uninitialized constant Mobility::ActiveRecord::StringTranslation Hmm... You have idea?

Comment: require 'mobility/active_record/string_translation' helps

Comment: Yes you 're right!! I just tested it to the console. You need the require 'mobility/active_record/string_translation' otherwise you have to  load first the  Post.all